# Android Facebook SDK Eclipse Proguard

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook, proguard

I've installed the Facebook SDK and has no errors but I can't seem to export it as part of my android project. I get the below error when enabling ProGuard:

```
Warning: com.facebook.applinks.FacebookAppLinkResolver$2: can't find referenced class bolts.Task$TaskCompletionSource
Warning: com.facebook.applinks.FacebookAppLinkResolver$2: can't find referenced class bolts.AppLink$Target
Warning: com.facebook.applinks.FacebookAppLinkResolver$2: can't find referenced class bolts.AppLink
Warning: com.facebook.applinks.FacebookAppLinkResolver$2: can't find referenced class bolts.AppLink$Target
Warning: com.facebook.messenger.MessengerUtils: can't find referenced class bolts.AppLinks
Warning: com.facebook.messenger.MessengerUtils: can't find referenced class bolts.AppLinks
   You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
Warning: there were 62 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
      You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

I added the below to my ProGuard file but I still get the error:

```
-keep class com.facebook.** {
   *;
}
```

How should I configure ProGuard to use the Facebook SDK?

Answer (score 3):

I am using these settings in my proguard-project.txt:

```
# Facebook Audience Network
-keep class com.facebook.ads.** { *; }
-keep class com.facebook.ads.internal.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.ads.mediation.facebook.FacebookAdapter {*;}
-keep class com.google.android.exoplayer.** {*;}

-dontwarn com.facebook.ads.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.exoplayer.**
```

Answer (score 0):

ProGuard is telling you that the Facebook SDK references classes in the `bolts` package but ProGuard can't find those classes because, most likely, you're not including Bolts in your application.

To fix this, you can either:

1. Tell ProGuard to ignore the missing dependency by adding the line

   ```
   -dontwarn bolts.**
   ```

   to the ProGuard configuration file. Doing this shouldn't cause a problem because the Facebook SDK can detect internally whether Bolts is present and only try to use it in that case.
2. Add Bolts as a dependency of your project by putting these lines in your Gradle file:

   ```
   dependencies {
      compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0'
      compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-applinks:1.4.0'
   }
   ```

Option 1 is probably the best choice unless you actually need Bolts.